# Cannot Find `Microsoft.Azure.Graphs` package in Nuget Packge Manager

Tags: nuget, azure-cosmosdb

As you can see in the following image, I cannot find `Microsoft.Azure.Graphs` package in Nuget Package Manager.

[image]

So, the question is why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the last version of the Graph Cosmos DB library is not released officially for dotnet, You should checked the "Include Prereleas" in the VS likes the following.

[image]